# How do you split a string into two array items in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I am currently working with an array of strings. Each string represents a user's comment, which includes a date, time, and of course, the actual text of their comment. My objective is to style the date and time differently than the text.

Unfortunately, the system has no predefined way to access the date or time of the comments only. So my question is then, if my string looks like this:

01172017 09:09:09 EST Hello, My name is Sahil.

How would I go about separating 01172017 09:09:09 EST from Hello, My Name is Sahil, with each having their own index in an array. This assumes that the date and time portion will always have the same amount of characters (or length rather).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the date and time strings have the same number of characters, you can do it in the following way using [**substring()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) method

```js
var str = "01172017 09:09:09 EST Hello, My name is Sahil"
var arr = [];
arr.push(str.substring(0, 21));
arr.push(str.substring(22));
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: If the time string format is fixed, both answers above work. If the time zone string has a different length, then it might fail. Usually I would split string wig blanks to get the real time string and return the rest as comment.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use substrings:

```
var str = '01172017 09:09:09 EST Hello, My name is Sahil.';
var arr = [str.substr(0, 21), str.substr(22)];

// gives ["01172017 09:09:09 EST", "Hello, My name is Sahil."]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: It should be s.substr(), `a` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it you have 2 options.

Option 1:

```
var str = "01172017 09:09:09 EST Hello, My Name Is...";
var array = str.split(" ");
```

Split takes the string and breaks it up into an array split up by what ever string is in the parameters. In this case a space (" "). So split would give you:

```
["01172017","09:09:09","EST","Hello,","My","Name", "Is..."]
```

Option 2:

```
var str = "01172017 09:09:09 EST Hello, My Name Is...";
var array = [];
array[0] = str.substring(0,8);
array[1] = str.substring(9,17);
array[2] = str.substring(18,21);
array[3] = str.substring(22);
```

Here substring takes each segment i.e. the date time and timezone and puts it into an array position. Here it's a little longer but you get the message as an entire string. Your array would look like this:

```
["01172017","09:09:09","EST","Hello, My Name is Sahil"]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do

```
    var str = ""
    str1 = str.split("")
```